# PowerShell Invoke to get CPU usage

Tags: c#, powershell, cpu-usage

Really frustrating because it seems to be so close to solution but can't get the last piece working.
I need to get CPU usage using C#.  PerformanceCounter is out the question because it takes forever to load the first time.  So trying to use PowerShell (System.Management.Automation.dll) to execute what looks like a simple line:

```
(Get-CimInstance Win32_Processor).LoadPercentage
```

This is C#:

```
var cpuUsage = powerShell.AddCommand("Get-CimInstance").AddArgument("Win32_Processor").AddCommand("LoadPercentage").Invoke();
```

So you can see I'm trying to pipe `LoadPercentage` command but it won't work.

> System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: 'The term
> 'LoadPercentage' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
> script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
> if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
> again.'

The rest of code works.
Can anyone please spot the issue here?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: From the sample powershell, it looks like `LoadPercentage` is a property, not a command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `LoadPercentage` is a property of the object, not a command. If you capture the result of the command and iterate through it's members, you should find what you're looking for:

```
var results = PowerShell.Create()
    .AddCommand("Get-CimInstance")
    .AddArgument("Win32_Processor")
    .Invoke();
        
foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.Members["LoadPercentage"]?.Value);
}
```

Comment: Nice, thank you very much!  Gotta love PS (especially when you know it well).